# Infinite loop in squares iterator

Tags: python, oop

I wanted to make an iterator to print a square of numbers in the range each time.

```
class Squares:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.start > self.stop:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.start = self.start ** 2
            return self.start


   for i in Squares(1, 10):
       print(i)
```

But finally, by executing the above code, we realize that an infinite loop is created from the starting point and the next method does not properly control the iterative process.

Comment: `1 ** 2 == 1`, so `self.start` never changes.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Pshaw! Changing the input number solves the prbolem; but the pritnted number is still out of range.

Comment: Ex: i in range(2, 10) OUT is 4, 16!  while 16 is out of range.

Comment: that is because you check the value and stop AFTER returning it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment `self.start` by 1 and return its square number:

```
class Squares:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.start > self.stop:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            res = self.start ** 2
            self.start = self.start + 1
            return res


for i in Squares(1, 10):
   print(i)
```

Out:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```